# What is a 3-state storage register on a shift register?

Tags: shift-register

The question lies almost all in the title
I have bought a shift register to play with, and looked at the datasheet.
I don't understand what is the 3 state storage register associated with RCLK.

My understanding is that if there is a high edge on RCLK then something (the 8 bits I guess) is stored in the storage. Is it possible to retrieve this value for some late usage ?

shift register 74HC595 with storage: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/733

datasheet : https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/IC/SN74HC595.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3-state simply refers to the ability to disable the outputs, in this case using the OE pin for output enable. It really has nothing to do with the registers themselves, but only the output drivers. Doing it this way allows to set up a bunch of devices on a common bus; for example, a shift register like this could receive the current state of a NES controller, and be read out at a later time.

Page 3 of the datasheet shows the functional steps very clearly; there's one shifting chain, fed by SER and SRCLK (with output into QH' so you can chain it wider, as for a SNES controller), a second 8-bit register that is updated using RCLK, and buffers to read that out using OE. This setup allows one set of counting hardware to load new values without risking a partially shifted version of data on the outputs.

So yes, RCLK will copy the shift register contents into the parallel output register. From there the only readout available is using OE to enable the output pins QA through QH. That makes the 74*595 a serial to parallel shift register.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand. If you the storage is like a 1 byte memory that you write using RCLK rise edge, how do you read this value later ? I thought that OE high will just allow the shift to happen when SRCLK rises

Comment: No, OE doesn't affect the storage, including shifting, at all - it's only for readout. When OE is active (low in this case), the '595 drives the QA-QH pins. The sort of behaviour you describe is often done in CE (chip enable or clock enable) pins.

Comment: To reformulate what you say, with OE enabled, on SRCLK rise, a new bit is read. When RCLK will trigger, this new bit will be pushed and the other bits are shifted, that's why it says it "stores" them. Is that correct ?
RCLK acts like a delay between input and output

Comment: @Thomas read the datasheet carefully. SCLK controls the shift register, accepting a new bit while pushing the older bits through the chain of 1-bit memory cells. RCLK copies each shift register memory cell to a corresponding holding cell. The purpose of this is to copy to the holding regsiters only when a full 8-bit value is shifted in. Otherwise the intermediate 'result' while the new 8-bit value is shifted in (one bit at a time) would be visible at the outputs.

Comment: @Thomas: No, that's not at all what I said! I said that OE does not affect what either CLK does *at all*. There are only three steps of data transfer: SRCLK moves things along the shift register, RCLK copies into a separate storage register, and OE reads that storage register out on external pins. Each operates independently.

Comment: Thanks all, I think I got it. Just to rephrase for any reader in the future (Im a complete noob so things might be easy for you but not for me) : there are 2 bytes. One that is displayed on the pins (B1), and another one (B2). on SRCLK, data from B2 is shifted. on RCLK, a copy of B2 is made onto B1 and shown on the pins. SRCLK and RCLK are pretty much independent.